# Slack how to update a message's interactive button after user's click?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I need to do exactly this:

[image]

I send the message using `chat.postMessage` and my understanding is that to achieve what's in the gif, the original message has to be updated using `chat.update`. The problem is I cannot find the correct JSON structure anywhere in Slack docs. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Docs I've checked:

https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments

https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages

Original message:

```
{
    "channel": "channenID",
    "text": "Some text",
    "attachments": [{
        "text": "Attachment text",
        "callback_id": "my_callback",
        "actions": [{
            "name": "action",
            "type": "button",
            "text": "Button text",
            "style": "primary",
            "value": "Some value"
        }]
    }]
}
```

What should the updated JSON be to achieve what's in the gif?

Comment: Well I already knew the answer in the other post, which is to use `chat.update` and a modified version of the original message. It's just that I can't find any docs on the modification I need to do to make it happen.

Comment: just replace it with a normal attachment that contains the message